# Netbeans "New File" - "Web services client" missing option

Tags: netbeans

If I create a new maven project in Netbeans 7, I can add a "Web Services Client" filetype to it, and it reads the wsdl and generates stub objects.  I have another pre-existing maven project, that Netbeans can import and build fine.  However, if I try to add a file of type "Web Services Client", (New File -> Web Services), the option isn't there.

Why could this be?  i.e. what defines in Netbeans what file types you can add to what projects, especially in this case with maven projects?

If it's relevant, the 2nd project is based on Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the EE edition:
http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=javaee